# Ошибка при конвертации данных Double

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть данный баланс 19955.35 он отображается вот так http://prntscr.com/n02cai. Я ищу по локатору его, потом конвертирую 
games = pageobject / BalanceTextPartners = locator(xpatch) double balance = Convert.ToDouble(games.BalanceTextPartners.Text);  появляется данный ерор Message: System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format. Подскажете как правильно будет, так как потом сниму некую сумму и буду через Assert.AreNotEqual сравнивать

Comment: если вы пытаетесь конвертировать текст в Double и у вас валится FormatException  то вероятно надо заменить `.` точку на запятую `,`. Зависит от вашей локали.

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble(games.BalanceTextPartners.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Путь 1

У Double парсинга есть настройки культуры. В нашем регионе один разделительный знак, в сша -- другой. Да и вообще можно выставить кастомный знак-разделитель. В твоем случае должен сработать

```
    Convert.ToDouble(games.BalanceTextPartners.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

## Путь 2

Extension для парсинга decimal числа со строки(string).

Краткая суть экстеншна:

- Не важно число на начале, середине или конце строки.
- Не важно Там будет только "голое число" или куча "мусорных" символов.  Лишние символы будут убраны.
- Не важно какой делимитер стоит в настройках винды -- точка или запятая: будет парсить оба символа успешно в любом случае.
- Возможность задать делимитер вручную.

  ```
  public static class StringExtension
  {
      public static double DoubleParseAdvanced(this string strToParse, char decimalSymbol = ',')
      {
          string tmp = Regex.Match(strToParse, @"([-]?[0-9]+)([\s])?([0-9]+)?[." + decimalSymbol + "]?([0-9 ]+)?([0-9]+)?").Value;

          if (tmp.Length > 0 && strToParse.Contains(tmp))
          {
              var currDecSeparator = System.Windows.Forms.Application.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

              tmp = tmp.Replace(".", currDecSeparator).Replace(decimalSymbol.ToString(), currDecSeparator);

              return double.Parse(tmp);
          }

          return 0;
      }
  }
  ```

Как использовать:

```
"It's 4.45 O'clock now".DoubleParseAdvanced(); // возвратит 4.45
"It's 4,45 O'clock now".DoubleParseAdvanced(); // возвратит 4.45
"It's 4:45 O'clock now".DoubleParseAdvanced(':'); // возвратит 4.45
```

Comment: вы этот код прямо в проде используете (путь 2)? Он решает какую то задачу, но определенно не предназначен для парсинга чисел. Ведь ткого не должн быть `"It's 4.45 O'clock now".DoubleParseAdvanced();` - это неправильный тест, если говорить только о парсинге числа

Comment: @tym32167 Второй путь заточен, скорее, для его личных задач. И, да, оно решает и парсинг и убирание лишних символов в строке, окроме числа.И да, я согласен c утверждением что это не совсем парсинг.

Comment: Тогда вопросов нет :)