# String Convert Double(Windows Form)

Tags: c#, winforms

Создаю приложение ползователь вводит километры нажимает ок и он считает метры и видет на экран! Но когда пишем например 456,545 ожидаемый результат 456545 но он печатает на экран 456545000 почему ? что неправильно писал ?

```
using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace KmsarqelMetr
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9')
                    return;
                if (e.KeyChar=='.')
                {
                    e.KeyChar = ',';

                }
                if(e.KeyChar==',')
                {
                    if(textBox1.Text.IndexOf(',')!=-1)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    return;
                }
                if(Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
                {
                    if(e.KeyChar==(char)Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        button1.Focus();
                    }
                    return;
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                double km;
                double m;
                try
                {
                    km = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                    m = km * 1000;
                    label2.Text = m.ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    textBox1.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: попробуй поставить точку вместо запятой в текстбоксе. Скорее всего все дело в знаке-разделителе настроенного в операционке.

Comment: Спасибо поменял все работает

Comment: посмотри еще вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958641/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-double/958643#958643